# convert any date format into YYYYmmdd in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to convert any date format to in YYYYmmdd and want to calculate the age accordingly

user is free to insert date in any format(no restriction on format)

```
19990212(YYYYmmdd)
12021999(ddmmYYY)
1999-02-12(YYYY-mm-dd)
12-02-1999(dd-mm-YYY)
and son on
```

```
set @dob_c='19990212';
select if(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date(@dob_c), CURDATE())>=21 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date(@dob_c), CURDATE())<100,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date(@dob_c), CURDATE()),0)
```

result of the above query is correct 21, but when I change the format of the date it gives me `null` as a result

```
19990212(YYYYmmdd) >>> result is 21
12021999(ddmmYYY) >>> result is 0
1999-02-12(YYYY-mm-dd) >>> result is 21
12-02-1999(dd-mm-YYY) >>>result is 0
```

my query is not working for all date format,

I want to calculate the age based on any date format but it's not working

Comment: The usermay be able to enter the date in sny format, but then your application should convert the result into proper mysql date and store it like that. Don't leave it to mysql to figure out the correct pattern on the fly when you want to do some operation with the date!

Comment: I am trying with older data that I have. I have changed the table structure for the upcoming new records

Comment: All the same, handle this in application code.

Comment: Without context, I'm afraid it is not necessarily possible what you want. For example, what date does `12-02-1999` represent? 12 February or 2 December? Even if it is possible, I probably would do this in an external program, with better error handling and better documented pattern matching functionaity. Because that's what you need: test the values with various patterns and convert the value to date using the best fitting pattern.

Comment: as @Shadow said i would reccommend also to intercept the user date in order to mantain the same formate once you have to store it into the database. For the old data it'better to to make an sql script to fix the format to a single one maybe adding another column with date type. Unless you do this you'll have problem time by time trying to recognize date

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem. For the old record have variations in date format

So I use `case` to solve my problem

```
SET @meta_value:='1989-03-02';
SELECT 
case 
   When LOCATE('-',@meta_value) = 0 then ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@meta_value, '%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d'),'')
    When LOCATE('-',@meta_value) > 0 then ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y%m%d'),'')
end as t
```

This will work for all the date formats I have. I am converting all the date formats to `YYYYmmdd` format. This will help me to maintain consistency. an I will update all my old record in this format only